# Изменить тип графика

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

у меня есть csv файл, по которому я строю график.
https://dropmefiles.com/4vUsn

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать его сплошной линией, подскажите как это сделать. Пытался изменить его тип, получалась либо просто линия, начиная от 0 и под углом 90 градусов вправо, либо вообще попросту исчезала.
Вот как я это делаю

```
data = pd.read_csv("C://Users//vlz//pjct//venv//2.csv",header=None, usecols=[0,6],
        names=["year", "val"], index_col=0)
        data = data.query(("{} <= year <= {}").format(A,B))
data.plot()
```

A и B - данные, которые я получаю из комбобоксов, по факту это диапазон годов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что у вас в переменных A и B ?

Comment: A = (int)(value2)
B = (int)(value3)

Comment: это года, к примеру 1980 и 2000

Comment: как понять "одной линией"?

Comment: сейчас загружу скриншот пример графика

Comment: вот типа такого, где нет этой ступенчатости или как это еще назвать

Comment: совершенно непонятно какие данные брать. На каждый год есть примерно 50 строк данных.

Comment: да, все верно, на каждый год данных как раз под кол-во недель в году (52)

Comment: а по поводу данных, график строится используя первую колонку (года) и последнюю, нужные мне значения

Comment: Тогда вам нужно строить график по неделям, а не по годам. Потому что по годам получается, что все 52 точки по Y попадают в одну точку на Х, в итоге получаются вертикальные линии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как совершенно справедливо заметил [Эникейщик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA),
попробуйте сначала преобразовать фрейм так, чтобы учитывались недели, а затем уже отрисовать график:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
data = pd.read_csv("2.csv",header=None, usecols=[0,1,6], names=["year", "week", "val"])

data['date'] = pd.to_datetime((data["year"]*100+data["week"]).astype(str) + '0', format='%Y%W%w')
data = data.set_index("date")

ax.plot(data["val"])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное! именно то, что я и искал!

Answer (score 4):

У вас есть 85 значений `-1`:

```
In [39]: data.query("val < 10")
Out[39]:
      val
year
1981 -1.0
1981 -1.0
1981 -1.0
1981 -1.0
1981 -1.0
...   ...
2004 -1.0
2004 -1.0
2004 -1.0
2004 -1.0
2004 -1.0

[85 rows x 1 columns]
```

можно их исключить и нарисовать график:

```
data.query("val >= 10").plot()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме того у вас есть несколько значений меньших `20`:

```
In [43]: data.query("0 <= val < 20")
Out[43]:
        val
year
2007  19.07
2007  17.07
2007  15.92
2007  14.98
2007  14.23
2007  13.79
2007  13.41
2007  13.28
2007  14.36
2007  16.52
2007  19.82
```

Comment: Да, все верно, есть данные, которые, наверное, портят график, как -1, но они тоже нужны, например -1 значит, что в этом году данные отсутствовали и тд. Проблема в построении заключается в этих данных или как, немного не понял вас, или же может быть я непонятно сформулировал вопрос в теме